# What corresponds to UIKit Dynamics in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uikit-dynamics

I'm specifically interested in **electricField()** and **magneticField()**.

Is there any similar SwiftUI library?

Comment: Any news on it?

Comment: Nothing new, @Zaphod. **SpriteKit with SKFieldNode, magneticField, electricField** etc are still the only built-in options in SwiftUI.

Comment: Too bad... Thanks @h4master anyway, UIKit Dynamics was really a cool way to have fun with the UI...